# Activate windows on a network with authentication

Tags: windows, windows-8-preview, windows-activation

I have installed a windows 8 consumer preview on my PC.

But there is a network with authentication required. When I try to activate windows, it doesn't ask me for credentials, and it shows an error...

Isn't there any way to activate my windows?